# Access computer from both internet and internal network

Tags: router, routing

I work in a software development company and I have fairly common request from my boss that I need to execute. Setup the company's svn server to be accessible from both the internal network and the internet. Here's what the network looks like and what I've done so far:

1. Windows computers in local network all connected to a D-Link DIR615 router
2. Router connected to the internet
3. svn server installed on a computer in the local network
4. port forward on the router to redirect traffic on svn port to svn server

Now the svn server is accessible from the internal network using the internal IP address and from the internet using the router's public IP (which is static). But the problem is that it's not accessible from the internal network using the public IP. Is there any way I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Tie the server to a fully-qualified **DNS Name** e.g. svn.yourcompany.com

- On your external DNS, tie the DNS name to the SVN repo's public IP.
- On your internal DNS, tie the DNS name to the SVN repo's private IP.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I already have an FQDN tied to my external IP address, but how do I tie the internal IP to the FQDN in a D-Link DIR 612 router?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to not use an IP address to connect, use a DNS record (like svn.mydomain.com) and have it resolve to the correct IP address on the outside and the inside respectively.